# How does Callable return or deal with exceptions?

Tags: java, concurrency

Im trying to throw an exception in one of the processes under `tasks.add` (the exception occurs in `paymentDao,savePayment()` method) , but that exception never shows up in my logs even though I see the thrown exception line being reached in the debugger. I expected the exception to be caught in one of the below catches but it never reaches there. Can someone explain how callable treats an exception that occurs within one of the tasks

```
private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100,namedThreadFactory);
List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
      if (cacheService.isPayment(
          (PaidPending) logProcessor.getCache().asMap().get(fileName), fileName)) {
        tasks.add(
            () -> {
              long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              paymentDao.savePayment(paymentR, fileName);
              log.info(
                  "Time taken by savePaymentSummary Key {} : {}",
                  key,
                  System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
              return null;
            });
      service.invokeAll(tasks);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new CustomException("Failed to insert payment " , e);
    } catch (CustomeException e) {
        log.error("Error here {}", e);
        throw new CustomException("Failed to fetch Payment", e);
    }
```

Comment: Note: `Callable` doesn't _do_ anything. The `call()` method that _you_ wrote does something when it is called by the thread pool. Maybe it throws an exception, in which case, the thread pool will catch the exception and store it in the `Future` that it created when you submitted your task. See my answer, below for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `Callable` task, `c`, that you `submit` to a thread pool throws any `Throwable` object, `th`, then `th` will be stored in the `Future` object, `f`, that was returned by the `submit(c)` call. A subsequent call to `f.get()` will then throw an `ExecutionException`, `exex`, and you can call `exex.getCause()` to obtain the original `Throwable`, `th`.

Your example calls `service.invokeAll(tasks)`, which returns a list of `Future` objects, but you do not bother to save the list.

Try this:

```java
List<Future<ResultType>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    ...
    futures = service.invokeAll(tasks);
}
catch (...) {
    ...
}

...optionally do something else before awaiting results...

for (Future<ResultType> future : futures) {
    try {
        ResultType result = future.get();
        ...do something with result...
    }
    catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        Throwable originalException = ex.getCause();
        ...do something with originalException...
    }
}
```

Note: `ResultType` is a proxy for whatever your `Callable` tasks return. I am not sure what type that should be, since in your example, the only value returned is `null`.  Maybe `ResultType` should just be `Object`.